# How to set on the center fab button on Ionic 4?

Tags: css, ionic4

i have two questions:

1. How to set it correctly in the middle? **WITHOUT BEING BEHIND THE ION CARD PLEASE** I tested a lot of things but the problem the fab button hid behind the ion-card, my code:

> ```
>   <ion-grid>
>       <ion-row>
>         <ion-col text-wrap>
>           <ion-card-content color="medium">
>             {{ object.body }}
>           </ion-card-content>
>         </ion-col>
>       </ion-row>
>       <ion-row>
>         <ion-col>
>           <ion-fab-button color="danger" [disabled]="disableButton">
>             <ion-icon name="flame" (click)="soSad()"></ion-icon>
>           </ion-fab-button>
>         </ion-col>
>       </ion-row>
>     </ion-grid>
> ```

[image: FABNOTCENTERED]

2. How could I order properly the icons with the badge to make it looks great? I mean, the icon and the badge closer and the next icon-badge next with a little space, or i can accept some ideas :) My code is:

   ```
         <ion-card-content>
               <ion-grid>
                   <ion-row align-items-start>
                       <ion-col>
                           <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
                       </ion-col>
                       <ion-col>
                               <ion-badge color="secondary">{{ object.see }}</ion-badge>
                       </ion-col>
                       <ion-col>
                           <ion-icon name="flame"></ion-icon>
                       </ion-col>
                       <ion-col>
                           <ion-badge color="danger">{{ object.zharko }}</ion-badge>
                       </ion-col>
                       <ion-col>
                           <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
                       </ion-col>
                       <ion-col>
                           <ion-badge color="warning">{{ object.fav }}</ion-badge>
                       </ion-col>
                   </ion-row>                     
               </ion-grid>
           </ion-card-content>
   ```

[image: badgeiconunordered]

UPDATED:

New problem with the code :S Now i need to fix this problem, cause i need to dont overlap the text, maybe in the middle of the bottom-edge of the ion card? but not behind the ion-card, any idea please?

[image: needtofixit]

Comment: provide a valid code so we can help u!

Comment: ITS VALID CODE, what do you mean?

Comment: snippet/codepen ?

Comment: Don't know how does it work, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-card-content>
        <ion-fab vertical="center" horizontal="start" slot="fixed">
          <ion-fab-button>
            <ion-icon name="share"></ion-icon>
          </ion-fab-button>
       </ion-fab>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row align-items-start>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                        <ion-badge color="secondary">{{ object.see }}</ion-badge>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-icon name="flame"></ion-icon>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-badge color="danger">{{ object.zharko }}</ion-badge>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-badge color="warning">{{ object.fav }}</ion-badge>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>                     
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-card-content>
```

It would help you.

Comment: New problem with your code jaja thanks buddy it works, but now its overlapping the text

Comment: You must use in the bottom of the page

Comment: I did it, but dont result... at the end i applied i put a ion-fab on a row inside the grid and put padding top 80px, fixed :) and im sorry, it doesnt work the align items, its not what im looking for...

Comment: now u use some css property for your work with rows and grid and col.

Comment: Always welcome. it's a platform for a developer for their solution.